# Oracle database 19c client installation failed with windows server 2016

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to install oracle database 19c client in windows server 2016. The installation process encountered an error "Failed to create oracle Oracle home user" After progressing 68%.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Did you call the setup as admimistrator? Ensure that any folder name (incl. the folder where you stored the setup) does not contain any **space** or non-ascii character.

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit. I have checked the folder name but it does not contain any space or non-ascii character.

Comment: Which options did you make to install the client?

Comment: I selected Administrator option.